# In camel route defined reply-to topic:result is changed to queue:result

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have the following camel routes defined:

```java
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("jetty://http://0.0.0.0:8082/api/message")
            .log("Received a request: ${body}")
            .log("${headers.JMSReplyTo}")
            .to("activemq:topic:request?replyTo=topic:result&replyToType=Exclusive")
            .log("${headers.JMSReplyTo}")
            .stop();

    from("activemq:topic:request")
            .log("${headers.JMSReplyTo}")
            .setBody(simple("message sent"));
}
```

I expect the second route to receive on topic activemq:topic:request and send to the topic:result.

The logging looks like:
[image: logging]

I don't understand why it is changing to a queue.

In activeMQ console result is showing in queues.
[image]

The second route is just for test purposes. The request topic is implemented by a third party and they expect "topic:result" in the JMSReplyTo header.

How can I send topic:result in the JMSReplyTo header?